# Setting up Privoxy with TOR

Tags: .net, vb.net, proxy, tor

So I have I coded a program in Visual Basic but the Visual Basic uses the default IE settings for the internet.

I was wondering that if I can setup IE with Privoxy and connect Privoxy with TOR. I know that Privoxy uses 127.0.0.1:8118 but I have no idea how to connect Privoxy with TOR.

***Cant you just google that?***
I did try that, trust me, but everytime i search, i see pages from 2009 using the old TOR guides. If you dont know what im talking about, Privoxy use to be bundled with TOR but was dropped support somewhere between 2010-2011 and there is no guides about it.

To make things even worse, there is no simple settings in Privoxy that I can use to connect to it, i have to edit this text file and it does not say where I must edit on the text file (I checked the website and no help there too)

Im only trying to open a .onion website using my Visual Basic 2010 program (it uses .NET Framework 4) so if anyone has any easier options (like a built-in SOCKS5 proxy) that helps. I did try connecting IE with TOR and it successfully shows im on the TOR when checking "http://check.torproject.org" but when attempting to access a .onion site, it fails.

Anyone can help me with this? I tried every possibility that I can think of yet still fail :(

Thanks!

Comment: looks like the new recommended proxy is polipo although privoxy is still supported